# How to search for old work items in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

I want to find all the work items in my Azure Devops tenant that have not been touched in the last 365 days.

I came up with the query Changed Date < @StartOfDay('-365d') but this does not seem to be giving me the expected results, as it includes newer items too.

Answer (score 0):

I have many work items on my side, but I didn't encounter the situation you mentioned.

What is the Changed Date of the 'newer items' on your side?

[image]

Comment: There is a variety, you can even see in your screenshot the item changed on 1/4/2021 12:50 PM should not appear in the list because it was edited a few days ago

Comment: @JanMartin Hi Jan, I think It's 2022 now. It's more than one year ago. If it was edited a few days ago, it should be 1/4/2022 12:50 PM.

Comment: Ah I see, you are using US date format - I am using dd/MM/yyyy, this is probably a bug